# Does a Custom IComparer affect SortedList Efficiency

Tags: c#, algorithm

If I give my `SortedList` a custom `IComparer` does that affect the lists `Lookup` and `Insertion` efficiency and algorithm?

I know that by default the `SortedList` uses a Binary Search for lookup and insertion. By making my own custom comparer will `Lookup` and `Insertion` still be done by Binary Search? Will a custom comparer affect efficiency now?

```
 SortedList <double, GO> list = new SortedList(new MyComparer());

 public class MyComparer : IComparer
 {
     public void Compare(double a, double b) {
         ...
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `SortedList<K, V>` uses the `IComparer<K>.Default` for comparing keys if you don't provide the comparer in the constructor. There is no functional difference beyond that.